# Confused on Susan Wolf's perspective on free will and moral responsibility

Tags: free-will

Is she saying that determinism has to be false in order to have moral responsibility and free will? Or is she saying that it's just impossible to have moral responsibility and free will?

Comment: Welcome to philosophy stack exchange!  To ask good questions, it would be useful for you to review the FAQ linked in the upper right of this page.  Specifically, https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  Making your question more explicit -- IE "in paper X, Susan Wolf wrote [.....].  But in paper Y, she wrote [...].  These appear contradictory (or unclear, or whatever) because .....  Can anyone clarify what she means by  ...."  This would assist others in answering your question, and make the answers more relevant by sharing what you have read and are thinking.

Comment: As @Dcleve said, a quote or reference is needed. We need to know what Susan Wolf *says* before we can talk about what she *means*.

Comment: See [Information Philosopher on Wolf](https://www.informationphilosopher.com/solutions/philosophers/wolf/). She is a typical compatibilist, free will for her is "*acting in accordance with Reason*" and compatible with determinism. "*Wolf follows Peter Strawson in arguing that whether or not determinism is true, humans exhibit moral behavior in their "reactive attitudes" toward the behavior of others when they express blame and praise for their actions (or when they feel guilt and pride about their own actions). For Wolf, this is enough to establish the existence of moral responsibility.*"

Comment: Is it fair to say that free will and moral responsibility require a sanity and deep self condition?